# how to make a connection string for oracle that includes hostname, instance name, user id, password using system.data.oracleclient?

Tags: oracle, odbc, connection-string

I have made a connection string in oracle like:

```
Data Source=hostname;Initial Catalog=IMPORT_UTILITY;User ID=abc;password=123
```

I want to make the same for oracle. I am using **ODBC**.

can anyone tell me what will be the connection string for oracle that will be equivalent to above sql connection string using odbc?

Answer (score 8):

For Oracle 12c R2 and the Instant Client ODBC Driver (version 12.2.0.1.0) the following connection string should work without having to create a DSN and/or a tnsnames.ora file:

```
DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_2};DBQ=HOST:PORT/SERVICE_NAME;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD
```

Example ODBC connection string for the Oracle 12c R2 docker image:

```
DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_2};DBQ=127.0.0.1:1521/ORCLPDB1.localdomain;UID=sys;PWD=Oradoc_db1 as sysdba
```