# R to Oracle Connection Using ODBC

Tags: r, oracle, odbc

I am trying to make a connection from R to Oracle and I am having issues doing so.

Here is the connection script I am using with the DBI and odbc packages:

```r
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "Oracle in OraClient11g_home1",
                      Server   = "orasade06.hc-sc.gc.ca",
                      SID = "sdv11040",
                      Schema    = "STG",
                      Username    = "username",
                      Password   = "pw",
                      Port   =  1521)
```

I am able to make a successful connection through Oracle SQL Developer to view my database and schema.

I have installed the Oracle ODBC driver (Oracle in OraClient11g_home1) on my machine, however I cannot make a successful connection from "R".

Here is the error I get:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: IM002: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Oracle or SQL Server? These are two different relational databases. Do not mix ODBC drivers.

Comment: I'd suggest the ROracle package.

Comment: @Parfait sorry I updated my connection script in my question. I had the wrong driver from another script. This is the error I am getting now:

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: IM002: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: @SmokeyShakers I'd love to, but I am not able to install an Java based R Packages as it's blocked in my organization.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Comment: @Parfait The driver I put in still does not work so I am trying to figure out what is the correct driver string to use

Comment: @SteveM I'm out of my depth here, but it seems odd that you've got Instant Client but not jre

Comment: Is the driver string your using included in `odbc::odbcListDrivers()`? Do you see an already-created DSN (pre-configured connection information) in `odbc::odbcListDataSources()`?

Comment: Your error is still inconsistent in post and above comment. Oracle is not a Microsoft product.

Comment: @r2evans there is no Oracle driver listed with the odbc::odbcListDrivers().

Do I need to get the Oracle driver installed on my machine?

Comment: Um ... yes, yes you do. (And I'm sure it's related, but ... your error does not match your code.)

Comment: Have you considered using the ROracle API? https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html

Comment: I have installed the Oracle ODBC driver and updated my question. I am still getting a driver error for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a tutorial around this, maybe take a look :

https://guillaumepressiat.github.io/blog/2019/11/oraclyr

Some key points :

- If your Oracle client is 32-bit, using R 32-bit is a (or the) solution. Otherwise R and odbc error messages aren't crystal-clear
- In RStudio see if an Oracle client appears in Connections Pane

It's easier on linux but strings and parameters for odbc are a little different.

Lastly, for connection string, this answer is interesting : [how to make a connection string for oracle that includes hostname, instance name, user id, password using system.data.oracleclient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578810/how-to-make-a-connection-string-for-oracle-that-includes-hostname-instance-name/46203817#46203817)