# Connection Oracle R Distribution

Tags: r, oracle, ddl, roracle

Hello I am trying to make an `R and Oracle connection`, however when loading the necessary `libraries` to start writing the code it marks me this error, **although the installations have been carried out correctly**
Thanks!!

The instructions https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/r/E96257_01/installing-ord-and-ore.html and packages download https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/r-enterprise-downloads.html.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGD4e.png)

Comment: It's best to update your post and describe exactly what you installed and how, since obviously the install _isn't correct_ otherwise it would work.  Have you followed the steps etc from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, practically followed the instructions in https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/r/E96257_01/installing-ord-and-ore.html for version 12.2.0.1. 0, and install the packages client and support for R version 3.3.0 https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/r-enterprise-downloads.html .

Comment: See here if it can help you, you have to install Oracle client and ODBC, and the platform matters (32b / 64b) https://stackoverflow.com/a/65483263/10527496